# Sum rows (Group By) in a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I have a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
ProductId CountThisWeek CountLastWeek
        1            10            15         
        1            20             5

        2             5            10
        2            10            15
        2            10            20

        3            10            15
```

I need to obtain a new DataTable by "compressing"(sum by productId) my initial DataTable, like this :

```
ProductId CountThisWeek CountLastWeek
        1            30            20         
        2            25            45
        3            10            15
```

is there a way to do it (.NET 3.5) using LINQ or other techniques?

Comment: the downvoter could maybe explain?

Comment: What have you tried?  What research have you done?  What problems are you having with your implementation to this problem?  See the tooltip for the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from r in table.AsEnumerable()
group r by r.Field<int>("ProductId") into g
select new {
   ProductId = g.Key,
   CountThisWeek = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("CountThisWeek")),
   CountLastWeek = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("CountLastWeek"))
}
```

You can use [`CopyToDataTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) method to create new `DataTable` from these anonymous objects.

Comment: it does not recognize "id" in the current context (inside the select new {...}), but g.Key seems to work...

Comment: @serhio oops, sorry. Fixed

Comment: The using of CopyToDataTable really suks.... I created the microsoft ObjectShreder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) to use this method with any kind of T, but now the call to the method is ambigous between the CopyToDataTable<DataRow> and CopyToDataTable<T>(with shreder)...

Comment: @serhio simplest solution is giving another name for your custom method. Whats wrong with `ToDataTable<T>`?

Comment: thanks! One more question... What will be the `g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("CountLastWeek"))` if one of the r["CountLasWeek"] is DBNull.Value? Perhaps I should set `Field<int?>`...